# Convex triangulations

Tags: graph-theory, discrete-geometry, planar-partitions

Given a set of $n$ points in the Euclidean plane of which no three are collinear, does there always exist a *convex triangulation* and how can one be found algorithmically?

In this context a ***convex triangulation*** shall mean a triangulation in which the union of triangles with a common corner-point inside the convex hull constitute to a convex polygon.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nice idea but it seems not to always exist:

---

[image: ConvexTriangulation]

          

<sup>Point $4$'s star is reflex at $3$,
Point $3$'s star is reflex at $4$.</sup>

---

Here's an argument that those are the only two triangulations.
Each interior point ($3$ and $4$) must be degree-$3$ or
degree-$4$: degree-$3$ to span more than $180^\circ$,
and at most degree-$4$ because there are only four other points.
In the left figure point $3$ has degree-$3$ and point $4$ degree-$4$,
and in the right figure point $3$ has degree-$4$ and point $4$ degree-$3$.
There must be a total of $9$ edges, $6$ of them diagonals. 
Then the diagonals in the two figures are forced.

Comment: It is an interesting question: *When* does a convex triangulation exist? And what is the computational complexity to decide if a set of points admits a convex triangulation?

Comment: Observation: If all neighbors of an interior vertex $v$ in a convex triangulation are interior vertices, then the degree of $v$ is at least $5$.

Comment: @JanKyncl: May I ask how you arrived at this interesting fact?

Comment: When looking at the figure, I noticed that around a vertex of degree at most $4$, two of the consecutive angles will sum up to more than 180 degrees. So the neighbor along the edge common to those two angles will have a nonconvex union of incident triangles.