# Convex Triangulations II

Tags: graph-theory, discrete-geometry, planar-partitions

While the original question [Convex triangulations](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/353268/convex-triangulations/353274#353274) was aimed at the existence and calculation of convex triangulations of a given set of $n$ points in the Euclidean plane, I would like to ask the opposite

> **Question:**
>
> where do pointsets, that come close to the ideal of having a convex Delaunay triangulation, "naturally" occur?

It appears to me that the pointsets that are generated via [Weighted Voronoi Stippling](https://cs.nyu.edu/%7Eajsecord/stipples.html) algorithms diagrams or the nuclei of 2D biological cell structures are almost free of non-convex maximal unions of Delaunay triangles with a common inner points as a vertex.

Comment: Perhaps the more fruitful direction is to try to expand  @JanKyncl's comment at the [originating posting](https://mathoverflow.net/a/353274/6094) that internal degrees need to be $\ge 5$, to understand the structure of these triangulations. Maybe only then will it be clearer where these "naturally occur."